# Angular Component Input variable not the same as the template

Tags: angular

This looks to me like something broken with the Angular framework.  Version information below.   I have a component that looks like the following -- only the relevant bits are included:

```js
export class RepliesComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @Input() serial: number;

  // ...

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('RepliesComponent.ngOnInit', this.serial);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log('RepliesComponent.ngAfterViewInit', this.serial);
  }
```

The template has this:

```html
<h3>Replies Component: {{ serial }}</h3>
```

The parent template has this:

```html
    <div *ngIf="doc">
      <h3>Replies Here: {{ doc.serial }}</h3>
      <app-replies [serial]="doc.serial"></app-replies>
    </div>
```

You just can't get more basic than that.   But here is what I get:

The parent template renders the expected number and the `RepliesComponent` template renders the same expected number like this:

```
Replies Here: 58
Replies Component: 58
```

Both `console.log` statements output `undefined` for the number.  And of course all the
logic depending on that variable breaks.

```
RepliesComponent.ngOnInit undefined
RepliesComponent.ngAfterViewInit undefined
```

So the component state is different from the template's state.   Does anyone have any idea of how this could happen, or what I can do to debug it?   I have been stuck on this for a day or two and any help appreciated.

```
% ng version

Angular CLI: 8.3.21
Node: 12.11.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.21
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.21
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.21
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.21
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.14
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.21
@angular/cdk                      8.2.3
@angular/cli                      8.3.21
@angular/flex-layout              8.0.0-beta.27
@angular/material                 8.2.3
@bazel/typescript                 0.39.0
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.14
@schematics/angular               8.3.21
@schematics/update                0.803.21
rxjs                              6.5.4
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

Comment: You're probably logging before it's set - when does ngOnChanges get triggered relative to those logs?

Comment: What is your `ChangeDetectionStrategy`?

Comment: What happens if you `<div *ngIf="doc?.serial as s"><app-replies [serial]="s"></app-replies>`?

Comment: Also can you provide a small example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)

Comment: Given that it was solved due to something not in the question, I'd recommend deletion.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I thought the same thing but the critical behavior that I think others could learn from is that the HTML rendered display cannot be relied upon to determine component state at an earlier time.  I could see others falling into the same trap I did but maybe this isn't a good example to learn from.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the input variable is used from the time when the component was initalized. To follow the value changes of the input, you will have to use a setter and getter:

```
@Input('serial') set serial (value: number) {
this._serial = serial
}

get serial(): number{
    return this._serial;
}
```

or follow the input changes by using the OnChanges hook:

```
public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   if(changes.serial) {
      this._serial = changes.serial.currentValue
   };
}
```